# How to approve uploaded files wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I approve uploaded images in wordpress.
I am not asking for the code but general.

I have done research. It works only for comments.

**My Code**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type='file' name='file'>
<input type='submit' value='send'>
</form>
upload();

function upload(){
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
$attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'file');

//No error when submit button is pressed with file
if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) { 
    echo 'BIG TIME ERROR';
} else {
    echo 'BIG TIME SUCCESS';
}}}
```

Comment: So are these images that are uploaded by your users? 
Is it the administrator that is approving the photos? 
What do you want to do with approved photos?

Comment: Images are uploaded by users. It is sent to the administrator to approve like comments. When approved, images are displayed on page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all the data (if there is any) and the file, you'll need to store as a custom post type:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

If you mark each of those post types as Draft when they're created than the WP admin will need to go in to the admin system and moderate them by publishing any that are ok, and deleting others.

You can then loop through all of your custom post types knowing that any that you can access have been published.

This may also be of use:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-submitted-posts/